# Is there any storage for the blocks in blockchain?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, substrate-node-template

I was working on migrating data from one blockchain to other blockchain. I have migrated much of my data. Now i was trying to migrate the blocks of the blockchain.I want to know that where is the storage for blocks produced in blockchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way you can migrate blocks from one chain to another chain. You can only migrate data from one chain to another. Data like Staking ledger, System Accounts, Contracts and any other things. But cannot migrate Blocks

Answer (score 1):

Each node is storing the block header, transactions and justfication in its own local database.

If you are migrating from one chain to another, it doesn't make that much sense to migrate the blocks. Your users will not need these blocks to sync the new chain as the new chain has their own blocks from genesis.